# How can I solve this issue: NoReverseMatch, in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

Good day, I'm receiving the following error:

```
Reverse for 'product_list_category' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['item/(?P<category_slug>[-\\w]+)/$']
```

at this particular line:

```
 <a href="{{ option.get_absolute_url }}">{{ option.name }}</a>
```

I'm not really seeing anything wrong with it.
This is how it looks in the template:

```
{% for option in categories %}
            <li {% if category.slug == option.slug %} class="selected"{% endif %}>
                <a href="{{ option.get_absolute_url }}">{{ option.name }}</a>
            </li>

        {% endfor %}
```

and in my models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
""" Model for a category """
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Meta:
    ordering = ['name',]
    verbose_name = 'category'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('store:product_list_category', args=[self.slug])
```

and in my views:

```
def products_list(request, category_slug=None):
category = None
categories = Category.objects.all()
products = Product.objects.filter(availability=True)
template = 'store/products.html'
if category_slug:
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
    products = products.filter(category=category)
context = {
    'category': category,
    'categories': categories,
    'products': products
}
return render(request, template, context)
```

and my urls:

```
 url(r'^$', products_list, name='products'),
url(r'^item/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', products_list, name='product_list_category'),
```

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you sure your object has `slug` set? The exception shows that it's try to reverse lookup using the empty string as the only arg.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper not sure of understand what u said

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper yes it does have a slug. my category has only two fields, name and slug

Comment: Right, but if your instance has `''` as the slug it would produce the exception you're seeing. The field is not declared as `blank=True`, so currently that would not be a valid slug to enter, but that doesn't tell us anything about the state of the database.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper do you mind being more explicit

Comment: Well, there are many ways to check your data - you should probably be comfortable enough in your underlying database shell to check that, something like `select * from appname_category where slug = '';` where `appname` is the name of your Django app. Or use a Django shell and check `Category.objects.filter(slug='')`.

Comment: The core problem I am suggesting is that you have at least one category where the `slug` field is the empty string. When `get_absolute_url` is called for that category, it passes the empty string to `reverse` as the argument (as you can see in the traceback). The empty string does not match your regexp, which requires at least one slug character, so the reverse does not match any known URL pattern.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper thanks for your guidance. used the django-admin site and saw one of my slug was blank. will make sure to give it at least a default now

Answer (score 1):

Try passing slug as `kwargs={'category_slug'=self.slug}` on the get_absolute_url function.
(would write this as a comment but I haven't got enough rep)

Comment: same result, its doing the same thing

Comment: i've forgot the "" on the 'category_slug'

Comment: Problem solved on the official comments, forget about me then